# linked list of files in a directory with append at last

Tags: c, linked-list, directory

I am trying to brush my linked list concepts. As an example I am trying to create a linked list with files of a directory, in serial order.

```
struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *prev = head;

    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir("/var/amit12/test1/");
    if(d) {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
            if(dir->d_type == DT_REG) {
                struct node *last = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                char full_path[18 + strlen(dir->d_name)];
                strcpy(full_path, "/var/amit12/test1/");
                strcat(full_path, dir->d_name);
                last->song_id = open(full_path, O_RDONLY);
                last->name = full_path;
                last->next = NULL;
                if(head == NULL) {
                    head = last;
                    prev = last;
                } else {
                    prev->next = last;
                    prev = last;
                }
                //prev.next = &last;
                //prev = last;
                printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
            }
        }
        closedir(d);
    }

printf("printing\n");

    struct node *root = head;

    while(root != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", root->name);
        root = root->next;
    }
```

This seems to always end with a seg fault.

Comment: Two things. (1) you're one by shy on your string length calculation, and (2) `last->name = full_path;` is *not* going to bode well. Each iteration of the loop destroys that automatic var `full_path` and once the loop terminates you have a list that is full of invalid name pointers. You need to make a dynamic *copy* of the name you're building.

Comment: @WhozCraig (1) Ahh right! (2) What would be the correct way to correct this?

Comment: @WhozCraig nvm, dynamic copy. Didn't read that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As WhozCraigh say you have to `malloc` each time `fullpath`, or at each iteration it will be destroyed.

This will do the job:

```
struct node *head = NULL;
struct node *prev = head;
char *full_path = NULL;

DIR *d;
struct dirent *dir;
d = opendir("/var/amit12/test1/");
if(d) {
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
        if(dir->d_type == DT_REG) {
            struct node *last = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            full_path = strnew(strlen("/var/amit12/test1/") + strlen(dir->d_name);
            strcpy(full_path, "/var/amit12/test1/");
            strcat(full_path, dir->d_name);
            last->song_id = open(full_path, O_RDONLY);
            last->name = full_path;
            last->next = NULL;
            if(head == NULL) {
                head = last;
                prev = last;
            } else {
                prev->next = last;
                prev = last;
            }
            //prev.next = &last;
            //prev = last;
            printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
        }
    }
    closedir(d);
}

printf("printing\n");

struct node *root = head;

while(root != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", root->name);
    root = root->next;
}
```